# how to access an enum from a library on the aidl server side

Tags: java, android, enums, aidl

I have a library from a third party vendor.  This library has an enum that I can access on the aidl server side.

This enum (and the library it resides in) is inside an AIDL service.

Now, the problem is: on the client side, how do I access this enum?

I understand that if I defined my own enum and make it implements Parcelable, then my enum can be accessed on the client side.  However, this enum belongs to a third party library.  Is there a way to access it from the client side?

Answer (score 0):

If this enumeration belongs to a third-party library and is passed to a client, then it seems that it should implement parcelable interface; or this enum is an internal part of another class that implements Parcelable interface. To get access to this enum you need to import this library into your project. Then you'll have possibility to communicate with the server.

However, you need to extend your question with details and code snippets to make it more clear. Then, we will try to help you.